# Trouble referencing a class that is being used in a method of another class

Tags: java, reflection, jar, treeview, classpath

I am making a Jar reflector tree for a program I am making for my internship, you load a jar file dynamically you want to see in the tree and through java reflection I get the names of the packages, classes and methods and display them in a treeView made with javafx. after the treeview is made i use the treeview's content to populate other aspects of my program.

The issue im running into is, even if i add the jar to my classpath, I still get noclassdeffound errors when a class is referenced inside a method of another class thats not found in that same jar.

for example in my class CollectionLexer there is a method

```
protected RuleContext parse(VocabularyStatementParser p) {
    return p.collection();
}
```

when i call (CollectionLexer full name).getDeclaredMethods(), it throws a noclassdeffound error for RuleContext, which is located in another jar.

Now, Ive got the ability to add the jar that RuleContext is in to the classpath dynamically, but it still throws a noclassdeffound error when i try and get the methods for CollectionLexer again.

```
public class JarFileLoader extends URLClassLoader {


    public JarFileLoader(URL[] urls) {
    super(urls);
   }

    private void addFilePath(String path) {

         path = path.replace('\\', '/');
         urlPath = ("jar:file:/" + path + "!/");
         try {
             addURL(new URL(urlPath));  
         } catch (MalformedURLException JarPathEx) {
           JarPathEx.printStackTrace();
         } 
    }


    public TreeItem<String> populateJarTree(BottomUp bottomUp, String jarFilePath) {

    this.bottomUp = bottomUp;

    try {
        jarFile = new JarFile(jarFilePath);
    } catch (IOException JarFileNotFound) {
        System.out.println("Jar File Not Found At Specific Location.");
    }

    jar = jarFile.entries();

    while (jar.hasMoreElements()) {
        jarEntry = jar.nextElement();
        if (jarEntry.isDirectory() || !jarEntry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            continue;
        }

        className = jarEntry.getName().substring(0, jarEntry.getName().length() - 6);
        className = className.replace('/', '.');

        try {

            addFilePath(jarFilePath);

            currentClass = loadClass(className);

            populatePackage();
            populateClass();
            populateConstructor();
            populateMethod();

        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError ClassDefEx) {
            String additionalJarFilePath = new ClassNotFoundPrompt().getPath();
            if (additionalJarFilePath != null) {
                addFilePath(additionalJarFilePath);
                populateMethod();
            }
            //Ignore class def error when it occurs
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ClassNotFoundEx) {
            ClassNotFoundEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return rootImport;
}
}
```

Comment: What happens if your class path contains all jars when you start the program?

Comment: If i include all jars that are needed before i compile and run the program it works just fine, but the whole point of that part of the program is to load any jar dynamically (aka i shouldnt have to include it before hand), if a noclassdef error is found I should be able to have the user give me the file path of the missing jar so i can add it to the classpath and continue the reflection

Comment: Your answer suggests that the dynamic extension of the class path does not work as expected. So maybe we look at the code you're using to do just that?

Comment: Ive updated my OP with some of the code im using

Comment: I'm not convinved that the scheme part "jar:file:" is correct (There shouldn't be an embedded ':', and I don't think the trailing "!/" is valid for a jar file. Got any references that back this up?

Comment: The terminating !/ separator indicates that the URL refers to an entire JAR file. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html

Comment: Looking at the (1.7) Javadoc of URLClassLoader: "Any URL that ends with a '/' is assumed to refer to a directory. Otherwise, the URL is assumed to refer to a JAR file which will be opened as needed." - Worth a try?

Comment: i removed the !/ which allowed me to move past the RuleContext class but now im stuck on another noclassdef even though it should be in the same jar.. ive been trying to find a solution for 2 days, my heads gonna explode

Comment: Take it easy. It seems that one problem has been solved, no? Start a new Q with the new problem?

Comment: its the same problem with a different class, Ill keep chipping away at it, i really appreciate your time and effort.